# Django select database objects based on previous query

Tags: python, sql, django, orm, models

I'm currently working on a project where there is twitter-style one way following, and I've been unable to figure out how to select 'posts' in the database based on who the user is following.

I'm using the default user functionality, and then this is my following model:

```
class Following(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="user")
    following = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="following")
```

and my posts model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    text = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Finally, the snippet from my view that I'm trying to get to work:

```
def home(request):
    following = Following.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    posts = Post.objects.filter(/*not sure what to put here*/)
```

I've been trying all night to get this working and I can't really see a solution, so any help would be awesome.

if there's anything that you might need to look at that I haven't posted here, the [github repository for this project is here](https://github.com/hzy-/Weld/tree/master/django/weld)

Comment: If I understood you correctly, maybe you should loop through the 'following' in the view and get all the posts related to each user. And then append the result to a list.

Comment: I think that would probably work, but then if you're following x people you have to make x sql queries, which I think would probably be incredibly detrimental for performance.

Comment: yes, but you can also use Complex lookups with Q objects as described in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects. I mean, loop through the 'following' and create a Q query. When you get out of the loop, run the query.

Comment: so something like... `posts = Post.objects.filter(for follow in followers: Q(user=follow),)` ?

Comment: Sorry, I forwarded you to the wrong direction. Please see the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My django is getting rusty, but here goes:

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(user__following__user=request.user)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.db import transaction

@transaction.commit_manually
def get_posts(following):
    posts = []
    for f in following:
        posts.append(Post.objects.filter(user=f))
    transaction.commit()
    return posts

def home(request):
    following = Following.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    posts = get_posts(following)
```